# How to remove the ngx-theme-switcher component from the ngx-admin header?

Tags: ng2-admin

How can I remove the ngx-theme-switcher component from the header of the ngx-admin template sample application?

I want to place it somewhere else but have not found any markup that uses the ngx-theme-switcher element.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can comment/remove   `<ngx-theme-switcher></ngx-theme-switcher>` in `src/app/@theme/components/header/header.component.html`